# Kafka Connect for Oracle setup on Windows

Tags: apache-kafka, windows-7, apache-kafka-connect

I was able to setup Kafka server/zookeeper on my windows 7 machine. Created a .NET app to produce and consume the application.

I now need oracle to consume the topic generated. I need some directions on setting up Kafka Connect on my Kafka running on Windows 7.

Please give me some directions on how to do that.

I am very new to Kafka. So far only thig I have done is setting up Kafka server on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data into Oracle from Kafka you can use the JDBC Sink connector. You can find details about this here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But based on what I read, we need Confluent Platform which is available only on LINUX and not on Windows.

Comment: Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka, not Confluent Platform specifically.

Comment: Thank you Robin. What about Cloudera Kafka. Can I still use Kafka Connect ? I don't see much documentation on how KC can be setup with Cloudera